# How do I exclude files/directories from the target directory using the maven war plugin?

Tags: maven-2, jetty, maven-plugin, pom.xml, war-filedeployment

I followed the instructions [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), and it worked but only if it was mapped to a directory other than the default.

Here's a sample that I tried:

```
<configuration>
     <webResources>
          <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
              <!-- the below works when uncommented and does exclude *.tmp -->
              <!-- <targetPath>test/WEB-INF</targetPath> -->
              <!-- the below does not -->
              <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*.tmp</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </resource>
      </webResources>
</configuration>
```

So my assumptions is that I have something else overriding the configuration. However, this is my first project using maven, so I'm not sure what to test or investigate next.

Answer (score 1):

change your exclusion to

```
**/*.tmp
```

You could also leave off the WEB-INF from the directory and remove the targetDirectory altogether.  For instance, here's one that would include all xml, xhtml, x*ml etc. and excludes all *.tmp in any directory

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.x*ml</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.tmp</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```